# why scalaz semigroup |+| for either type not take the left result as final result but for operation do

Tags: scala, scalaz

This is the code from scalaz document, so basically, if the value is left value, it will take this left value as the final result and stop evaluating the rest, which is very useful.

```
for {
         e1 <- "event 1 ok".right
         e2 <- "event 2 failed!".left[String]
         e3 <- "event 3 failed!".left[String]
       } yield (e1 |+| e2 |+| e3)  // event 2 failed
```

However, I have this code and I am using **reduceLeft** to append the value

```
object processor {
    def evaluate(x: Int): \/[String, Int] = {
      if (x <= 3) x.right[String] else ("some exception about " + x).left[Int]
    }
  }

val result = (1 to 6).map(processor.evaluate).reduceLeft(_ |+| _) 
//\/-(-\/(some exception about 4some exception about 5some exception about 6))
```

The left value is accumulated, which is not what I want. I guess the different behaviour caused by reduceLeft is "left" value is already evaluated while for operation (flatMap and map) would not.

How should I change this code to take the left result as the final result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use traverse syntax

```
val result = (1 to 6).toList.traverseU(processor.evaluate)
```

I convert range to List to get List type class in scope

Answer (score 1):

I *think* there may be some confusion about what is exactly going on in the following code

```
for {
  e1 <- "event 1 ok".right
  e2 <- "event 2 failed!".left[String]
  e3 <- "event 3 failed!".left[String]
} yield (e1 |+| e2 |+| e3)  // event 2 failed
```

In the code above, the for comprehension is using map and flatMap for `\/[+A, +B]`. The function defined by the yield statement will never be evaluated because of the implementation of map/flatMap for `\/[+A, +B]`. In this case it is map/flatMap which is doing the *merging* of the different `\/[String, _]`. The `|+|` operator used by the function in `yield`, is defined in SemiGroup syntax is simply using `Semigroup[String]` to combine the strings on the right side into one string. In the case above, it may as well be using `String.append`. I get why one might want to use `Semigroup[String]` to combine these opposed to simply `String.append` here, but the important part is that the function defined by yield is using `Semigroup[String]` and not something like `Semigroup[A \/ B]`.

In the case below, you **are** using `Semigroup[A \/ B]` to combine the `String \/ Int` instances into a single `String \/ Int`. `reduceLeft` (or `foldLeft` if you chose that route instead) is simply doing the wiring of each element in the list to the accumulation function it is passed.

```
object processor {
    def evaluate(x: Int): \/[String, Int] = {
      if (x <= 3) x.right[String] else ("some exception about " + x).left[Int]
    }
  }

val result: String \/ Int = (1 to 6).map(processor.evaluate).reduceLeft(_ |+| _)
```

From the definition of `Semigroup[A \/ B]`, we can see that it requires `Semigroup[A]` and `Semigroup[B]`.

If you instead used `Monad[A \/ _]` or `Applicative[A \/ _]` to combine the `A \/ B` in the function passed to `reduceLeft`, the `A`s would not be combined.

The following uses `Applicative[A \/ _]`

```
val result: String \/ Int = (1 to 6).map(processor.evaluate).reduceLeft {
  (xs, x) => (xs |@| x)(_ |+| _)
}
```

The following uses map/flatMap defined for `A \/ B` and is most similar to the code at the top.

```
val result: String \/ Int = (1 to 6).map(processor.evaluate).reduceLeft {
  (xs, x) => for {
    xsA <- xs
    xA <- x
  } yield xsA |+| xA
}
```

foldMapM might do what you want, but uses Foldable[List].foldsRight so your error will be different than if you used foldLeft. Unfortunately, an ugly type lambda, or the type alias below is needed.

```
type StringEither[B]=String \/ B
val result: String \/ Int = (1 to 6).toList.foldMapM[StringEither, Int](processor.evaluate)
```